# How to parse XML with Latin-1 Hex inside <>

Tags: python, xml, parsing, encoding, iso-8859-1

I have an XML which is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
    <body>
        <t id="1" word="w<E4>re"/>
    </body>
```

```
"w<E4>re"
```

is the German word "wäre". When I try to parse this xml with python lxml, I just get "w" instead of the full word, even if I apply encoding="iso-8859-1":

```
from lxml import etree as ET
for event, elem in ET.iterparse("myXML.xml", recover=True, encoding="iso-8859-1"):
    if elem.tag == 't':
    print(elem.attrib['word'])
```

How do I get "wäre"?

Comment: This looks like the file actually contains *wäre* and you used `less` to look at it. The file doesn't actually contain `<E4>` I guess.

Comment: And if it does contain `<E4>` within an attribute value, it's not well-formed XML and you won't be able to use an XML parser to process it.

Comment: Regardless, the best fix would be to change whatever tool produces this format.

Comment: @tripleee yup, that was the problem! Thanks a lot!!